# Post a form using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, post, action

I have following form tag:

```
<form id="Form1" action="https://www.example.com/" method="post" runat="server">
            <asp:HiddenField ID="p" runat="server" Value="1" />
            <asp:HiddenField ID="msg" runat="server" Value="2"/>
            <asp:HiddenField ID="cha" runat="server" Value="3"/>
            <asp:HiddenField ID="lang" runat="server" Value="4"/>
            <asp:HiddenField ID="number" runat="server" Value="5"/>
            <asp:HiddenField ID="amo" runat="server" Value="6"/>
            <asp:HiddenField ID="cu" runat="server" Value="7"/>
            <asp:HiddenField ID="co" runat="server" Value="8"/>
            <asp:HiddenField ID="cl" runat="server" Value="9"/>
            <asp:HiddenField ID="crl" runat="server" Value="10"/>
            <asp:HiddenField ID="sature" runat="server" Value="11"/>
            <asp:HiddenField ID="mk" runat="server"/>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Go" />
</form>
```

I would like to trigger the post action using JavaScript while page is loading!

I used following Javascript code to the Head tag to do so, but it is not working.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var myForm = document.getElementById('Form1');
        myForm.submit();
    });

</script>
```

Any suggestion?????

Edit1 : I tried provided solutions in [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133925/javascript-post-request-like-a-form-submit?answertab=active#tab-top) but wasn't solving my problem.

Edit2 : following scripts are added to form. (Head Tag). are they sufficient for this?

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: Seems suspicious. There must be a better way to accomplish what you want.

Comment: As you already use jquery you can simply write `$('#Form1').submit();` Well have u included jquery? :-P

Comment: why do you send the user back content for the user to submit rather than submitting it for them from your server?

Comment: @KevinB My thoughts exactly.

Comment: Define "it is not working". Does the form not get submitted, or does it get submitted without any data? Form controls must have a name to be successful.

Comment: @MarkusKottländer The added script is this : <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>

Comment: @RobG: Not working: It is not posting the form. tried fiddler and nothing being recorded there as well!

Comment: I don't understand why that is directed at me. I didn't ask about that.

Comment: @amirmoradifard then post your fiddler

Comment: Try pure JS: `window.onload=function(){document.forms['Form1'].submit();};`. If that doesn't work, there is something strange going on.

Comment: It was strange from the beginning. Sorry this did not work as well. When I put an alert('test') it is working, but there should be something wrong with my form. Right?

Comment: OK, found the source of problem. The <input type=submit was the source of problem.
thanks all!

Comment: @amirmoradifard—if you had included that in the original post it would have been pointed out directly. Do not give form controls names that are the same as form properties or methods.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To submit the form while the page is loading, put the script tag immediately after the form and do not wrap it in a document.ready (This answer is assuming you have jquery included in the head of the page, since you had it in your question)

```
<form id="Form1" action="https://www.example.com/" method="post" runat="server">
        <asp:HiddenField ID="p" runat="server" Value="1" />
        <asp:HiddenField ID="msg" runat="server" Value="2"/>
        <asp:HiddenField ID="cha" runat="server" Value="3"/>
        <asp:HiddenField ID="lang" runat="server" Value="4"/>
        <asp:HiddenField ID="number" runat="server" Value="5"/>
        <asp:HiddenField ID="amo" runat="server" Value="6"/>
        <asp:HiddenField ID="cu" runat="server" Value="7"/>
        <asp:HiddenField ID="co" runat="server" Value="8"/>
        <asp:HiddenField ID="cl" runat="server" Value="9"/>
        <asp:HiddenField ID="crl" runat="server" Value="10"/>
        <asp:HiddenField ID="sature" runat="server" Value="11"/>
        <asp:HiddenField ID="mk" runat="server"/>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Go" />
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#Form1').submit();
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks Zachallia, I tried this too but again nothing changed. I have provided the included script items in page. are they correct?

Comment: @amirmoradifard—You can remove the dependency on jQuery altogether using `document.forms['Form1'].submit();`. You don't need jQuerUI.

Answer (score 1):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#Form1').submit();
    });

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Using jQuery, do this on a `$('#Form1').submit(function(){ \\HERE });`

```
$.post("https://www.example.com/", $("#Form1").serialize(),  function() {
    alert("success");
}));
```

So in total:

```
\\Event that occurs when DOM is ready
$(document).ready(function () {
    \\Event binding that occurs when the element with ID `Form1` is submitted 
    $('#Form1').submit(function(){
        \\Calls the POST function in jQuery with the serialized form data
        $.post("https://www.example.com/", $("#Form1").serialize(),  function() {
            alert("success");
        })); 
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. This is not working as well. I think the problem should be from somewhere else!

Answer (score 1):

if you are using jquery you can do this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#Form1').submit();
    });

</script>
```